# What does the discovery of a pentaquark signify?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, pentaquarks

at a particle collider a [pentaquark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaquark) was discovered. My question in short is what does the discovery of a pentaquark signify? Is there a theory that it supports or something like that?

Comment: Phys.org: [New evidence from LHC shows pentaquark has a molecule-like structure](https://phys.org/news/2019-06-evidence-lhc-pentaquark-molecule-like.html), PRL: [Observation of a Narrow Pentaquark State, Pc(4312)+, and of the Two-Peak Structure of the Pc(4450)+](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.222001)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about the significance of the discovery of the Pentaquark. It would shed light on some mysteries surrounding the nuclear force, to begin with. It could perhaps lead to a change in what we understand about Neutron stars, too.

In terms of "some theory it supports or something like that", generally the stuff we already think still makes sense. Good!